# Google Image Search - Specify exact width with any height?

Tags: google, google-image-search

The Google image search has the ability to search for images with specific dimensions. For example, you can search for an image with an exact pixel width and height of your choice. However, if you enter one and not the other, it will be automatically set to search for the same value for both. Is it possible to search for one specified while leaving the other open for any value?

Comment: WHY DON'T USE __OPTION LARGER THAN__ FOR EXAMPLE: 300X400

Comment: In the Image Search I see, I don't have the option to enter "specific dimensions" - only to pick _approximate_ dimensions from a list? (@sabertabatabaeeyazdi: Why are you SHOUTING?)

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi: Because I'm trying to find images with an exact width (i.e. 256), but any height. Picking the larger than option would give me images with a width larger than the one I specified. That's not what I want.

Comment: @w3d: On the Google image search, click the "Search Tools" then the size dropdown, then exact to find images of an exact size.

Comment: @golmschenk: Ah yes, thanks! I was looking under "Advanced Image Search" where this option seems to have been omitted!?

Comment: Nope. you *have to* specify both. No option for working with just one yet.

Comment: @Bibhas: This seems to be the case on Google's search. Any site that uses a modified version of Google's search that can do this? Or any other good images searches that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as the only size operator is `imagesize` so you must give both dimensions

`puppies imagesize:50x50`

`puppies imagesize:50` gets dropped because Google doesn't understand the parameter given as it's not supported.